# Defining entries

Tags: php, mvc, comparative-review

I am working on my own PHP MVCframework. Now I want to know where to get and specify my entities.

For example, should I do this:

```
class User_Model extends Model {
 private $name;
 public getName() {}
 public setName($var) {}
 public getAllUsers() {}
 public getUser() {}
 public saveUser(User_Model $user) {}
}
```

or this:

```
class User_Model extends Model {
 public getAllUsers() {}
 public getUser() {}
 public saveUser(Entity $user) {}
}

class User extends Entity {
 private $name;
 public getName() {}
 public setName($var) {}
}
```

My favorit is the second example. The model is like a repository. But what's your opinion?

Comment: The type hinting in saveUser should be User not Entity. I like the second example more.

Comment: To me this seems like a relatively superficial  question amongst a sea of questions related to building a MVC framework, one that could even be open to your coding preference while building a site within your MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is an example of [Active Record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), which, I believe, violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by mixing the `Domain` logic with the `Persistence` logic. The second code snippet is thus better in that it separates the responsibilities.

The naming of classes is somewhat ambiguous and inconsistent with the commonly used terminology. The aforementioned responsibilities would often go into two separate layers (namespaces) called `Domain` layer (sometimes `Model`, `Entity`, etc) and `DataAccess` layer (sometimes `Repository`, `Mapper`, `Database`, `Dal`, etc). The `Domain` layer contains `Domain` objects, like `User` for instance. The `Domain` objects may extend a base class often called `[Abstract]Model` or `[Abstract]Entity`. The `DataAccess` layer may contain [`DataMapper`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), [`Repository`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), [`Dao`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), [`TableDataGateway`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) or [`RowDataGateway`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) classes depending on which strategy (Design Pattern) you choose for persisting the `Domain` objects.

So, eventually you might end up with something like the following.

**Package structure**

```
SomeModule/
    Domain/
        Model/
            User
        Service/
            SignUpService
    DataAccess/
        UserDao
```

**Classes**

Domain object

```
namespace SomeModule\Domain\Model;

class User
{
    private $name;
    public function setName($name) {}
    public function getName() {}
}
```

Data Access object

```
namespace SomeModule\DataAccess;

class UserDao
{
    public function findOneById($id) {}
}
```

I would also suggest that you look into some popular MVC frameworks ([Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/), [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/)) to get comfortable and confident with the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Model and Entity mean very similar things to me, an Entity being something like an instance of a Model.

What might be of use to you is to rename the Model class in the second example into a Collection class (Repository even). You would retrieve Entities from a Collection and save them back when they are done. This may have some advantages depending on the rest of your architecture and to me this looks better in terms of a separation of roles.